# How to update component when state changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Heyia, React noob here, sorry for possibly dumb question, I just started few days ago and can't really solve this.

I'm creating an array of objects containing data obtained from Twitter API and sending it back to App component where I want to work with it further.

I get the array, set it to the state of App component, but cannot achieve that the change is immediately shown on the page -- I mean printing the list right after username is obtained from user input and being processed by the function returning the array.

It is probably something simple but I haven't completely grasped the idea behind communication between components and their lifecycle (if those are relevant, I'm not really sure) so I cannot figure it out.

Can someone please help me?

This is my code

App.js file

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: "",
        tweets: []      // here I need to get the array of objects
    };

    this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
}

// following methods are used to first get a username by user input

submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.useUsername();
};

usernameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
};

// this one's calling the function for obtaining the tweets, code below

useUsername = () => {
    this.setState({tweets: fetchTweets(this.state.username)});
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Grid fluid>
                <Row>
                    <form>
                        <label>
                            Username:
                            <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.usernameChangeHandler}/>
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit" onClick={this.submitHandler.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <div className="jumbotron text-center">

                         // this should be updated when state changes
                        <Table list={this.state.tweets}/>
                    </div>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}
} 

const Table = ({list}) => {
return (
    <div>
        {
            list.map((item) =>
                <div key={item.id}>
                    <h3>{item.text}</h3>
                    <h4>by {item.author}</h4>
                    <h5>by {item.date}</h5>
                    <p>{item.num_of_likes} Likes; Mentions: {item.mentions}; Hashtags: {item.hashtags}</p>
                </div>
            )
        }
    </div>
)
};
```

Function processing the user input and returning the array

```
export const fetchTweets = username => {
let alltweets = [];
twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: username, count: 50}, function (error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            let tw = tweets[i];
            let newtweet = new Tweet(i, tw.text, tw.user.screen_name, tw.created_at,
                tw.favorite_count, tw.entities.user_mentions, tw.entities.hashtags);
            alltweets.push(newtweet);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Error occurred while retrieving tweets: " + error);
        return error;
    }
});
        return alltweets;

};
```

And this is the class of objects I'm creating from the Twitter data

```
export class Tweet {
constructor(id, text, author, date, num_of_likes, mentions, hashtags) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.author = author;
    this.date = date;
    this.num_of_likes = num_of_likes;
    this.mentions = mentions;
    this.hashtags = hashtags;
}
}
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of  the ```twitter``` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the fetchTweets function doesn't work right now is because the `twitter.get` function is *asynchronous*, meaning the stuff in the callback doesn't happen immediately after you call it. It happens a little while later. Here's what happens when you call it:

- The `alltweets` array is created, set to `[]`
- `twitter.get` is called
- The `alltweets` array is returned to the react component
- React sets the state to an empty array
- `twitter.get` finishes, has the results, and adds stuff to the array

The missing piece here is that `setState` needs to happen *after* `twitter.get` is finished, not before. The most straight-forward way of accomplishing this is to allow your `fetchTweets` function to accept another function which gets called when `twitter.get` is finished. Here's how to do that:

```
// new fetchTweets
export const fetchTweets = (username, handleResult) => {
  twitter.get("statuses/user_timeline", { screen_name: username, count: 50 }, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
      let alltweets = []

      for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        let tw = tweets[i]
        let newtweet = new Tweet(i, tw.text, tw.user.screen_name, tw.created_at, tw.favorite_count, tw.entities.user_mentions, tw.entities.hashtags)
        alltweets.push(newtweet)
      }

      // callback function is called here
      handleResult(alltweets)
    } else {
      console.log("Error occurred while retrieving tweets: " + error)
    }
  })
}

// in your react component
useUsername = () => {
  fetchTweets(this.state.username, alltweets => {
    this.setState({ tweets: alltweets })
  })
}
```

Comment: this seems to work well, thank you. also for the explanation, now I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Approach is not good one.

Make your function `fetchTweets` to return promise resolved with data or rejected with error.

```
export const fetchTweets = username => {
  let alltweets = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    twitter
      .get('statuses/user_timeline', {
        screen_name: username,
        count: 50
      }, function (error, tweets, response) {
        if (!error) {
          ///construct alltweets

          resolve(alltweets);
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
  });
};
```

Instead of calling `this.useUsername()` from `submitHandler`,call `fetchTweets` instead and `setState` within it.

```
submitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetchTweets().then((alltweets) => {
    this.setState({tweets: alltweets})
  }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Or if you can also try [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) / [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) instead of promise chain.